# Apply gradient on the whole SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to draw an SVG wheel what will be rotating and having a linear gradient. Moreover, while spinning, the wheel should have a gradient on the same place (top). I drew it:

```
<svg width="950" class="wheel" height="950" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
            <linearGradient id="wheel" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="50%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#fff"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#bec7cf"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="475" cy="475" r="430" stroke="url(#wheel)" fill="url(#lines)" stroke-width="10"></circle>
    <circle cx="475" cy="475" r="395" stroke="url(#wheel)" fill="transparent" stroke-width="10"></circle>

    <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="url(#wheel)" stroke-width="10"></line>
    <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="url('#wheel')" stroke-width="10"></line>

    <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="url('#wheel')" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(30 475 475)"></line>
    <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="url('#wheel')" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(30 475 475)"></line>

    <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="url('#wheel')" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(60 475 475)"></line>
    <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="url('#wheel')" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(60 475 475)"></line>

    <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="url('#wheel')" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(90 475 475)"></line>
    <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="url('#wheel')" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(90 475 475)"></line>

    <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="url('#wheel')" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(120 475 475)"></line>
    <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="url('#wheel')" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(120 475 475)"></line>

    <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="url('#wheel')" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(150 475 475)"></line>
    <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="url('#wheel')" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(150 475 475)"></line>
</svg>
```

But the gradient is rotating with figures.

[image: Gradient]

Is there a way I can group elements and apply a gradient on the whole group as one figure?

Comment: How are you spinning the wheel?

Comment: @RobertLongson rotating groups while rotating gradient backwards

Comment: I mean where is the code that does that?

Comment: @RobertLongson I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution but I believe there is one easier.

I created two groups with wheel lines. One of them has a second color of my desired color of my gradient, and another one is masked with a white-to-black gradient.

Then I animated it with `<animateTransform>`. While my wheel is spinning clockwise, my gradient is spinning backwards.

```
<svg width="950" class="wheel" height="950" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="wheel" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="50%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#fff"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#bec7cf"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <linearGradient id="transwheel" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="50%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#fff"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="475" cy="475" r="430" stroke="url(#wheel)" fill="transparent" stroke-width="10"></circle>
    <circle cx="475" cy="475" r="395" stroke="url(#wheel)" fill="transparent" stroke-width="10"></circle>

    <mask id="clipping" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <circle cx="475" cy="475" r="800" fill="white"></circle>
        <circle cx="475" cy="475" r="70" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>

    <mask id="gradient" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect x="0" width="950" y="0" height="950" fill="url(#transwheel)" transform="rotate(0 475 475)">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 475 475" to="-30 475 475" dur="3s" repeatCount="1"></animateTransform>
        </rect>
    </mask>

    <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 475 475" to="30 475 475" dur="3s" repeatCount="1"></animateTransform>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(30 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(30 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(60 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(60 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(90 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(90 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(120 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(120 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(150 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="#bec7cf" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(150 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
    </g>

    <g mask="url(#gradient)">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 475 475" to="30 475 475" dur="3s" repeatCount="1"></animateTransform>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(30 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(30 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(60 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(60 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(90 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(90 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(120 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(120 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>

        <line x1="457" y1="80" x2="457" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(150 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
        <line x1="492" y1="80" x2="492" y2="870.00" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(150 475 475)" mask="url(#clipping)"></line>
    </g>
</svg>
```